# Remotely Connecting an IPv6 Computer to a IPv6 Private Web Server

Tags: routing, ip, ipv4, ipv6

I have a private web server at my office, and I want to access that server remotely at my house via IPv6.

My office has both IPv4 and IPv6 enabled, but my home has only IPv6.

IPv4 works, but I have it routed to another service, that’s the reason for me wanting to use IPv6

Is there a way to connect to my web server from the house via IPv6. Placing the IPv6 address in brackets does not work remotely outside the office network, but it works locally with other devices in the office network.

I was thinking that the same IPv6 address would work directly anywhere in the world, since it is already the public IP address (not the local fe80:: range), and does not need any form port forwarding. My analogy was that since it works locally, then it should work to the outside world.

My Web Server has an IPv6 of: 2001:4454:10b:e700:53:fbfe:f08:xxxx

Is there a way to configure the server/router properly to make my server work with IPv6 remotely? Thanks!

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you can connect to global IPv6 addresses from any other global IPv6 network in the world. In practice, we have firewalls that block outside-initiated traffic from entering a network unless there is an explicit rule allowing it. A firewall will, by default, block all outside-initiated traffic, and you must create rules to allow any such traffic to enter the network.